# Combine the result of two queries in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have these tables:

```
User(idUser, name...)
Group(idGroup, name, ...)
```

And an associative table to relate them:

```
UserIsInGroup(idGroup, idUser...)
```

I made a query that brings the id's of all the groups in which the user I'm looking for appears.

```
select group.name, group.idGroup from Group
join UserIsInGroup
on group.idGroup = UserIsInGroup.idGroup
where UserIsInGroup.idUser = 1; /*User #1*/ 

select group.name, group.idGroup from Group
join UserIsInGroup
on group.idGroup = UserIsInGroup.idGroup
where UserIsInGroup.idUser = 2; /*User #2*/
```

Obviously, both queries brings a different result list, but they have a result in common which I want to take.

So, I want something like select(results in query #1 that are in query #2 too), but I have no idea of how to do that.

I hope you guys can help me, thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm guessing your table is not really called group

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

since i don't have enough reputation to comment i'm writing this as an answer. 
what about intersects?
EDIT: this solution is not for MySQL (I forgot about that when i wrote this answer) However, I'll leave it here just in case

```
    select group.name, group.idGroup from Group
   join UserIsInGroup
   on group.idGroup = UserIsInGroup.idGroup
   where UserIsInGroup.idUser = 1; /*User #1*/ 
    INTERSECTS
   select group.name, group.idGroup from Group
join UserIsInGroup
on group.idGroup = UserIsInGroup.idGroup
where UserIsInGroup.idUser = 2; /*User #2*/
```

i saw a reply with this solution posted, but apparently, it got deleted.

An alternative:

you can use INNER JOIN as a replacement for intersects, i tested it out  and it seems to be working:
Notice that you must give each select an alias, in this case I just used letters

```
select distinct * from (select group.name, group.idGroup from Group
join UserIsInGroup
on group.idGroup = UserIsInGroup.idGroup
where UserIsInGroup.idUser = 1; /*User #1*/ ) as a
INNER JOIN
(select group.name, group.idGroup from Group
join UserIsInGroup
on group.idGroup = UserIsInGroup.idGroup
where UserIsInGroup.idUser = 2; /*User #2*/) as b;
```

inner join returns all the rows in the two queries that have columns in common. I hope this helps or at least gives you an idea

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I hadn't used that operation until now, so it didn't come to my mind. 

Apparently INTERSECT doesn't exists in mysql, but you could simulate it as  
    select * from table 
    where [condition]
    and exists (select * from table 
                     where [condition])

https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/intersect.php

Anyway It doesn't work for me for some reason, I must be doing something wrong. I had to use temporary tables to save te results for the original queries and then join them. Thats the only way I have found to do that.

Comment: sorry, i was in a hurry and completely forgot about that, i think i've got another solution, i'm going to edit my answer